# Package an ES6 class from node to browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, browserify

I have been trying to package a super simple ES6 style class object to the browser. Example

```
class Foo {
   constructor(){
        this.name = "Foo";
   }
}
module.exports = Foo;
```

Sure I can use this in my node projects just fine, but it's also a useful object for the browser. So far I have tried webpack and browserify, but they do not expose the object globally. I was hoping to basically include the generated script file and be able to call `let foo = new Foo()` from the browser. How can I do this?

*note that literally the *only* thing stopping me from just including the file in the browser directly is the `module.exports`

Answer (score 3):

Without hacking a huge library, or building another node module to somehow automate this, I thought of that famous razor today and just did this.

```
if(typeof module !== "undefined"){
    module.exports = Foo;
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest way of solving the nodejs / browser module compatibility issue I have seen so far

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript 6 you wanna do something like:

```
class Foo {
   constructor(){
        this.name = "Foo";
   }
}
export default Foo;
```

(use export instead of module.exports)

Then from another js file do:

```
import Foo from '<path_to_foo>';
```

For example, if Foo.js is in the same dir as the "other" module, then you can do: `import Foo from './Foo';`

Then you can do `let f = new Foo()`

Modern browsers tend to support js modules, however it is not guaranteed.

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't work with node. I'm trying to make a simple class object available in node and the browser.

Comment: Oh , my bad. I thought you were trying to make a class available in the browser without using webpack and browserify. I don't think this is possible without those tools... Code in node exists in the server. NodeJs classes are like Php classes. Using webpack you create a bundle that reuses common code by duplicating some parts

Comment: I've tried using both webpack and browserify and I don't see a way to have my class declared in the global scope